# Need to append output from the python script to the file

Tags: python, linux, bash, shell

I'm trying to write a simple `shell` script to start and stop my python script. The reason I'm doing this is because I want to use tool called `monit` to monitor processes and I also would need to be sure that this script is running. So here is my python script:

## test.py

```
 import time
 
 for i in range(100):
     time.sleep(1)
     print 'a'*i
```

and here is my shell script:

## wrapper_test.sh

```
 #! /bin/bash
 
 PIDFILE=/home/jhon/workspace/producer/wrapper_test.pid
 
 case $1 in
   start)
     echo $$ > ${PIDFILE};
     exec /usr/bin/python /home/jhon/workspace/producer/test.py 1>&2 output
     ;;
   stop)
     kill `cat ${PIDFILE}`
     ;;
   *)
     echo "Usage: wrapper {start|stop}" 
     ;;
 
 esac
 exit 0
```

The result that I want is lets say I do `tail -f output` and I would see staff coming to the file. I also tried to change `1>&2` to just `>` but this creates file, and once I press `Ctrl + C` than all the data appends to the file.

But right now, I dont see anything

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For append (you never want to cut the file), use `>>`; to get the stderr too, use 2>&1

```
exec /usr/bin/python /home/jhon/workspace/producer/test.py >> output 2>&1
```

and

```
import time
import sys

for i in range(100):
    time.sleep(1)
    sys.stdout.write('a'*i)
    sys.stdout.flush()
```

Answer (score 3):

Replace `1>&2 output` with `> output 2>&1`:

```
 exec /usr/bin/python /home/jhon/workspace/producer/test.py > output 2>&1
```